# units of group ring $\mathbb{Q}(G)$ when $G$ is infinite and cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, cyclic-groups, group-rings

How would I be able to describe all units of the group ring $\mathbb{Q}(G)$ where $G$ is specifically an infinite cyclic group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could realize that this group algebra is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q[x,x^{-1}]$, the Laurent polynomials over $\Bbb Q$.

Since it is just  the localization of $\Bbb Q[x]$ at the powers of x, the units are easy to describe.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not familiar with Laurent polynomials, so I'll be sure to check this out further.  I know that the rationals form an integral domain (and $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field), so in this case (from my brief reading thus far), I can describe the units having the form $ux^{k}$ where $u$ is a nonzero element of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @user0990 Yes, and k is any integer.

Comment: Great, thanks so much; marking as answered

Comment: and just to make sure I understand, the isomorphism exists since G is a free abelian group here, correct?

Comment: can we say that $\mathbb{Q}(G)$ is a ring of fractions which is isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ of rational functions over $\mathbb{Q}(G)$ with one variable?

Comment: The isomorphism exists because here is exactly one infinite cyclic group, and the integer powers of X are just a multiplicative model of it.

Comment: I don't understand the other comment very much. It is certainly not isomorphic to a field because it is not a field.

Comment: @rschwieb I have a bunch of questions: 1. When user0990 says $G$ is a free abelian group, how does he know that? Because it's infinite cyclic, and so is isomorphic to one copy of $\mathbb{Z}$? 2. I don't know what a localization is - I've come across group rings and this problem in a first year graduate level algebra course, and we haven't learned anything that sophisticated. Would it be possible for you to edit your answer to explain it in simpler terms? 3. How do you know it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x,x^{-1}]$? That seems strange to me since $G$ is cyclic and should have only 1 generator

Comment: @ALannister 1. Yes. 2. You can solve the whole problem by working with Laurent polynomials and no mention of localization. 3. The integral powers of $x$ are obviously a group isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. The definition of $\mathbb Q[x,x^{-1}]$ and $\mathbb Q[\{x^n\mid n\in \mathbb Z\}$ amount to the same thing! The reason you need two generators is that ring multiplication only generates a monoid, not a group. You need to throw in $x^{-1}$ to finish generating the group.

Comment: @rschwieb, I deleted the last question I asked because I saw your post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595044/laurent-polynomials-ring (you should have just sent me there). One thing though, could you just explain how we know that the units in $\mathbb{Q}[x, x^{-1}]$ are of the form $ux^{k}$ where $u$ is a unit (nonzero element) in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @ALannister suppose two elements of the localization multiply to $1$. Cross multiplying, you get two polynomials in x multiplying to a nonnegative power of x. By unique factorization, both of the polynomials are scalar multiples of powers of x so that they are units in the localization. This is the most obvious argument... didn't you even see a little bit?