# Identify all units of the group ring $\mathbb{Q}(G)$ where $G$ is an infinite, cyclic group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, cyclic-groups, group-rings

This question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1574196/units-of-group-ring-mathbbqg-when-g-is-infinite-and-cyclic) one, in that I am asking about the same problem, but not necessarily about the same aspect of the problem.

I need to identify all units of the group ring $\mathbb{Q}(G)$ where $G$ is an infinite cyclic group.

Now, as I understand it, if $R$ is a ring and $G$ is a group, then if we consider the set of all formal sums

$$r_{1}g_{1}+r_{2}g_{2}+\cdots + r_{k}g_{k},$$

$r_{i} \in R$, $g_{i} \in G$, where we allow the empty sum to play the part of the zero element $0$,

then if we consider two formal sums to be equivalent if they have the same reduced form, the group ring $R(G)$ refers to the set of equivalence of classes of such sums with respect to this equivalence relation.

In this case, then, since $\mathbb{Q} = R$ and $G$ is some infinite cyclic group, say $\langle x \rangle$ (although, if it is an infinite cyclic group, couldn't we say that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?), so our sums look like

$$q_{1}x_{1} + q_{2}x_{2} + \cdots + q_{k}x_{k}$$

for some rationals $q_{i}$ and elements of $\langle x \rangle$, $x_{i}$.

Now, the units of this group ring are the nonzero, invertible elements, and that various relationships exist among units, principal ideals, and associate elements. I am not sure how to apply any of this information to this situation, though, as I am relatively inexperienced with working with group rings.

Moreover, I did find the answered question I linked to above, but this answer uses some terminology that I am unfamiliar with: for example, I do not know what it means to be a "localization of \mathbb{Q}[x]", and I only know a little bit about Laurent polynomials from Complex Analysis, which I'm assuming is where he is getting the negative powers from in his answer.

Now, among my questions is: **1. How do you know that $\mathbb{Q}(G)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x, x^{-1}]$?** That it is seems weird to me, since $G$ here is supposed to be cyclic, and he seems to be saying that a group ring on a cyclic group is isomorphic to a group ring on a group with two generators, but perhaps my confusion just stems from my inexperience with group rings? If someone could please explain this to me, I would be forever grateful. Also, **2. what is the actual isomorphism used or how do you show that the two group rings are isomorphic? 3. How does this tell us what the units are?**

I'm extremely confused and I thank you very much in advance for your time, help, and patience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify $\mathbb{Q}G$ is a group ring and $\mathbb{Q}[x,x^{-1}]$ is a ring of Laurent polynomials $p(x) = \sum_{i\in \mathbb{Z}} q_i x^i$. Since $G$ is a cyclic infinite group we write each $a\in G$ as $a = c^i, \,\, i\in \mathbb{Z}$, in the multiplicative form where $c$ is a generator of $G$. The map $c^i \mapsto x^i$ induces a ring iso between $\mathbb{Q}G$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x,x^{-1}]$. You should be able to check the details from here.

For the general notion of a localization of a ring there is much to say, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring

Comment: how does a map induce a ring isomorphism? I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I really want to understand.

Comment: Extend lineary to $\sum q_i c_i$ the rest follows from definitions of multiplication in $\mathbb{Q}G$ and multiplication of polynomials

Answer (score 2):

For a field $K$ and a group $G$, consider the formal finite sums of the form $$\sum_{g \in G} a(g) [g], \qquad a(g) \in K $$

Then this set becomes a ring $K[G]$ with the obvious addition :

$$\sum_{g \in G} a(g) [g] +\sum_{g \in G} b(g) [g]= \sum_{g \in G} (a(g)+b(g))[g]$$

And the  multiplication generated by $[g][g'] = [gg']$ the group law of the ring, so that :
$$(\sum_{g \in G} a(g) [g] )(\sum_{g' \in G} b(g') [g'])= \sum_{g \in G} [g]\sum_{h \in G} a(h)b(h^{-1}g)$$
(this multiplication is commutative iff $G$ is a commutative group)

Assume that $G = (\mathbb{Z},+)$ then we have a ring isomorphism $$\varphi : K[G] \to K[x,x^{-1}], \qquad \varphi(\sum_{g \in \mathbb{Z}} a(g) [g]) = \sum_{g \in \mathbb{Z}} a(g) x^g$$
And its units are the elements of the form $a(g) x^g, a(g) \in K^\times$, because the only polynomials being inversible in $K[x,x^{-1}]$ are the powers of $x$ times a constant (think in term of zeros/poles in the algebraic closure)

Comment: can you explain your notation $[g]$ in the $\sum_{g \in G} a(g)[g]$?

Comment: @ALannister I defined it. It is just to make it clear $[g]$ is not an element of the group nor a number